# Area of parcel on Autocad is deferent from ArcGIS and we need to rectify ArcGIS Area Calculations

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, autocad, autocad-map

I have a problem with the built in Area calculation field in ArcGIS and in Autocad map 3d area for the same feature. The issue happened specifically when using Arcs (Curves) .

The scenario is we have drawn using Autocad map 3d then we redraw it on ArcGIS in a different way, sometimes using trace and sometimes import or manual drawing. The issue is these different methods result in different area calculations between the ArcMap calculation field and Autocad query.

Any Ideas?

Comment: How different? Another difference that's related to the digitizing is that the features may have vertices in different locations.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your reply , the Area still different even the feature from the same vertices

Answer (score 1):

Ideas:

***Projection***. ArcMap will give you different area numbers *for the same data* if it's in different coordinate systems. It's important to ensure your data is in an appropriate coordinate system for what you plan to do with it (e.g., calcalating area should be done on a projection that preserves area and is suitable for the region being mapped, like a UTM zone for a city, etc.)

***Hand digitizing***. Since you said you copy the features in ArcGIS in part by manual methods, this can definitely introduce errors.

Comment: Thanks Paulo , This is helpful and this is reducing the Area difference but in large curved parcel the difference is still .